# Filter with combobox with datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm filtering the individual table column searching select inputs. It's working, but I wanted to be able to select more than one product.

Normal works, as I show:

```
initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select style="width: 350px;"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
```

But now how do I select more than one product, in the `html` of `select` I'm putting the `multiple`, but so does the filter no longer:

```
initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select style="width: 350px;"  multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, multiple values can be searched with `OR`. In regex, `|` is logical `OR`. So try joining the multiple values using `join('|')`

**DEMO**

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns().every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          column
            .search($(this).val().map($.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex).join('|'), true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Numero</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>155555</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: After putting it into operation, I noticed that there is a problem, some products that even exist says they can not find them

Comment: @BrunoPinto does that column data contain any special characters? if so, then try `$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex` with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) before `join()`

Comment: You are saying this: `.search($(this).val().$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex.join('|'), true, false)`. Yes, it has special characters

Comment: @BrunoPinto I have provided the `map()` link in the previous comment, visit there and read the docs, you will know what I'm trying to say. Hint - `$(this).val()` returns an array

Comment: @BrunoPint `.search($(this).val().map($.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex).join('|')` this may helps. not sure

Comment: Thank you, the problem was even that